# Best Practice: Where to place a function which is called from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby on Rails and the whole MVC style of doing things. This question isn't so much technical as it is conceptual. Say I have some function `myFunction` that I wish to have a user execute from the View by pushing a button. Should I have this function in thew Model, or the controller?

Comment: I can't get your question properly. What do you mean by saying `I wish to have a user execute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function relates clearly to a particular model e.g. "placing an Order", "authenticating a User" then place it on the appropriate model and add a small amount of controller code to create/retrieve the appropriate model and call the method.

If it doesn't obviously belong on one of your models then you may want to create a separate class or module for it, and again add a small amount of controller code.

Do some Googling for "[skinny controllers and fat models](http://www.google.com/search?q=skinny%20controllers%20fat%20models)", this is the approach generally favoured for Rails projects. e.g. see [this](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) (old, but still useful) post from Jamis Buck, or [this more recent post](http://qualityonrails.com/archives/33).

Answer (score 0):

It should goes to controller's method which is using models to do some business logic (not necessary connected with persistance). Probably, you should also read about RESTful apps and routing (there is a lot of guides about it).

Answer (score 0):

Controller's are just expected to have the Input and Output which is the request parameters and the response/redirect.  So according to you if a user clicks a button and `myFunction` should come into picture.  Put the call to `myFunction`  inside the view helper and the function `myFunction` inside the model.  So your View is also clean from code and the Skinny controller and Fat models come into picture